# Using basemap as a figure in a Python GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-basemap

I have snippets of code to generate a basemap, as well as the (very rough) start of a GUI.  However, I cannot find that "one-liner" will allow me to display the map as a figure in the GUI. Code snippets are as follows; ideally, I would like a couple of things to happen:

1. An image of the 'basemap' to relace the plot of `sin(2*pi*t)`
2. I would really like for the code to record the (pixel) location on the graphic, if I were to click on the plot shown (the hope is that you could click anywhere on the map, and the script would record the latitude and longitude of where you clicked).

Regarding the 1st step, I've tried things such as setting the figure variable, f, equal to the Basemap; this killed the GUI portion altogether, and simply showed an image of the map in another window.

I've tried to address #2 by trying to implement a couple routines I found on stackexchange, but never got it to work fully.

Basemap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

## User-chosen datapoint
#lons = [10]; lats = [20];

# Define map projection
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
```

Rough GUI:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# implement the default mpl key bindings
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t, s)

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def on_key_event(event):
    print('you pressed %s' % event.key)
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_event)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple technique is to define an `on_click` function, show an image, then overwrite that image.  The `on_click` function will still read the mouse click location, despite the image change.

A sample code follows, demonstrating this is as shown:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        print event.xdata, event.ydata
    else:
        print 'Clicked ouside axes bounds but inside plot window'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()

#Define map projection
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
```

Answer (score 2):

The question how to include a basemap plot into Tkinter has actually not been answered yet. So the idea is to create an axes `ax` in a figure and add the Basemap to the axes. This is done with the `ax` argument,

```
m = Basemap(..., ax=ax)
```

The figure is then added to the canvas in the usual way; below is a complete example.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c', ax=ax)
m.drawcoastlines()

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

*Note: In newer versions of matplotlib you should use `NavigationToolbar2Tk` instead of `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`.*

Comment: I want to know that if I want the Basemap to  get plotted on full canvas area then I will use ax.set_aspect('auto') before the line canvas.show() post which if I run the code then the Basemap seems to occupy the complete canvas area. Now the issue is if I try to zoom in a particular region of the map using "zoom to rectangle" option present in the Navigation toolbar then the map seems to be getting stretched and this is what I want to avoid. Can you explain why it is happening and how to avoid it.